# embed markdown table file to github wiki

Tags: github, markdown, github-flavored-markdown

I have a markdown table txt file on my GitHub repository that I am changing from commit to commit I want to embed this markdown table file as part of page on the GitHub wiki , that next time I commit the changes the GitHub wiki page  will be reflected automatically wit the new markdown table update.

any idea how can I embed a markdown table file on GitHub wiki?

Comment: Are you asking how to automatically  update the wiki with each commit, or how to embed a markdown table to a Github wiki?

Comment: I am asking how to embed markup wiki txt file from the repo  as part of GitHub wiki page

Comment: "With wikis, you can write content just like everywhere else on GitHub. For more information, see "Getting started with writing and formatting on GitHub." We use our open-source Markup library to convert different formats into HTML, so you can choose to write in Markdown or any other supported format."

https://docs.github.com/en/github/building-a-strong-community/about-wikis

Comment: The GitHb wiki is just another git repo. You could create a git hook on your project repo which detects changes to your text file and copies them to the relevant file in your wiki repo. I suspect you will find many existing answers if you search for how do those things.